# Converting 'N' number of rows in CSV format to XML file

Tags: python, xml, csv

Values given in CSV format is this

ColA ColB

0     1001

1     1021

2     1024

```py
import csv

f = open('Class.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
data = []
for row in csv_f:   
    data.append(row)

f.close()

print (data[1:])
```

data it print is following:
[['0', '1001'], ['1', '1021'], ['2', '1024'], ['3', '1037']

```py
def convert_row(row):
    return """<Class="%s"> %s""" % (row[0], row[1], row[2])

with open('output.xml','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([convert_row(row) for row in data]))
```

But here it throws errors :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

even though the index is not of out of range

And I wanted it to run for 'N' number of rows in excel

XML format I am looking for is this:

```
<Class>
<Id>1001</Id>
<Id>1021</Id>
<Id>1024</Id>
<Id>1037</Id>
<Id>1044</Id>
```

It would be a great help if anyone can resolve my issue.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html

Comment: To follow up on @Dominique, specifically, [Building XML documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents)

Comment: thanks Dominique and @ZachYoung for reference
I found out what i was looking for.